# can anyone explain the python following code(i'm complete rookie)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop

Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if `s = 'azcbobobegghakl'`, then your program should print  Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh.

In the case of ties, print the first substring. For example, if s = 'abcbc

```py
s = "azcbobobegghakl"

x = s[0]

y = s[0]


for i in range (1, len(s)): 

    if s[i] >= s[i-1]:
        y += s[i]   

    else:
        y = s[i]  

    if len(y) > len(x):
        x = y               
print(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

This smells like homework, but...
Here are comments explaining:

```
# assign a string to a variable named s
s = "azcbobobegghakl"

# assign the zeroth character of the string s to x
x = s[0]

# assign the zeroth character of the string s to y    
y = s[0]


# loop through a range of numbers starting at 1 and going to the length of s
# within each loop, the variable i tells us which iteration of the loop
# we're currently in.    
for i in range(1, len(s)): 
    # compare the character in s at the position equal 
    # to the current iteration number to see if it's greater 
    # than or equal to the one before it. Alphabetic characters 
    # compared like this will evaluate as numbers corresponding 
    # to their position in the alphabet. 
    if s[i] >= s[i-1]:
        # when characters are in alphabetical order, add them to string y
        y += s[i]   
    else:
        # when the characters are not in alphabetical order, replace y with
        # the current character
        y = s[i]  
    # when the length of y is greater than of x, assign y to x
    if len(y) > len(x):
        x = y
# after finishing the loop, print x
print(x)
```

Comment: It is indeed homework but my frustration got me here. I really appreciate your answer, can you also explain what is the purpose behind comparing y and x assigning y to x?

Comment: "your program should print Longest substring"
so you build a substring, and as you build it, you compare to the last one each time it changes. When it's longer, you save it. When it's equal or shorter, you just keep building alphabetical substrings.

Answer (score 0):

The `string` class in python contains `__lt__`, `__eq__` data-model methods, which enables us to do -

```
str1 = 'aaa'
str2 = 'bbb'
str3 = 'aaa'

assert str2 < str1   # Will lead to AssertionError
                     # '<' calls the __lt__() method of the string class

assert str1 == str3  # No AssertionError
                     #'==' calls the __eq__() method of the string class
```

These particular data-model methods in the `string` class compare the ASCII values of each character in the string. The ASCII values of each character in the english alphabet sequentially increases i.e. 'A' < 'B' < 'C'.

**Your code**

You loop through the string one character at a time (starting from the 2nd character), and check if the current character has a larger (or equal) ASCII value than the one before. If it does, that characters is added to the `y` string, and the resulting string is stored as `y`. If not, then y is replaced by the current character. At the end, if `y` has more characters than `x` you replace the string inside `x` by `y`.

Comment: This is what I was exactly looking for. Thanks  a ton really appreciate your effort. God bless you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you like, you can accept this answer.